# Chef PostgreSQL Cookbook Installs Wrong Version on RHEL 7

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, postgresql-9.3, rhel7

Running the latest version (6.1.1) of the postgresql Chef cookbook (https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/postgresql) with

```
node.default['postgresql']['enable_pgdg_yum'] = 'true'
node.default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.3'
```

This installs postgresql in /var/lib/pgsql/9.3, but running

```
psql -V
```

returns

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite more at least version, dir, client, contrib and server packages:

```
node.default["postgresql"]["version"]             = "9.3"
node.default["postgresql"]["dir"]                 = "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main"
node.default["postgresql"]["client"]["packages"]  = ["postgresql-client-9.3", "libpq-dev"]
node.default["postgresql"]["server"]["packages"]  = ["postgresql-9.3"]
node.default["postgresql"]["contrib"]["packages"] = ["postgresql-contrib-9.3"
```

It is just an example, I am not sure about package names, double check it. It is due to the way ruby evaluates strings.

Comment: This is the current solution. As you can already see in the github repo (https://github.com/sous-chefs/postgresql ), attribute-based configuration will become deprecated (no recipes anymore!) and replaced by a custom resources.